# opencv segmentation returning a black image

Tags: c++, opencv

I am currently working a segmentation project for a class and am required to create my own segmentation using any opencv function.  My original idea was to use the morphology gradients with a 5x5 kernel after filtering (because my previous testing showed that gradients give better edges which is what I want to do).  That produced a black image (and in case of one photo no result).  The code does compile and then decided on using a Canny Edge detection for testing.  That also produces the same result of a black image instead of the edge detection.  So now I am wondering if there is a silly mistake in the code I am using.

Code here (c++ using Xcode on OS X 10.10.2)

```
   //
            //  myseg.cpp
  //  
  //
   //  Created by Mobin Anandwala on 3/16/2015 updated on 3/17/2015.
  //
  //



    #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

 using namespace cv;

// Global Variables
        Mat image, image_gray, final, final_seg; 
       // source image grayscale image final       image final image segmented
       int const kernel = 5; // kernel size
       int const lowthreshold = 0; // for Canny
       // operator for morphologyEx function use Gradient
       int const maxlowthreshold = 20;
       int const ratio = 3;
       const char* window_name = "MySeg Output";

        void myseg(Mat &image)
        {

// implement blur filter to remove noise using 5x5 kernel
blur(image_gray, final_seg,Size(kernel,kernel));
Canny( final_seg, final_seg, lowthreshold, maxlowthreshold*ratio, kernel );
final = Scalar::all(0); // create mask
image.copyTo(final_seg,final);
imshow(window_name,final_seg);
   }

   /** Function Headers **/
   void myseg(Mat &image);

 int main()
{
      /// Load an image
      image = imread("/Users/mobinanand/ECE\     59500/Project2/myseg/Yosemite1.jpg",1);
      if( !image.data )
      { return -1; }

      final.create(image.size(),image.type()); // create final image marker
      cvtColor(image,image_gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);  // Grayscale

      myseg(image);
     /// Create window
     namedWindow( window_name, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
     imwrite("/Users/mobinanand/ECE\ 59500/Project2/myseg/test.jpg",final);

     waitKey(0);
     return 0;
  }
```

I've looked at the similar questions listed and they do not reference what I am looking for and it is quite possible that I made a stupid error somewhere along the line here that is not a code error but more like a PBEBKAC error, maybe some fresh eyes on it will show the error.

Comment: If you want to display anything with OpenCV `namedWindow()` you have to make sure that values of a displayed `Mat` are in 0.0 - 1.0 range.

Comment: So in this case is my final image basically a matrix of 0's?  I've tried modeling this based on the OpenCV example code and I thought I was applying the edge detection to the image I am displaying.   Do I need to print out the final image Mat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving to file "final" image:

```
imwrite("/Users/mobinanand/ECE\ 59500/Project2/myseg/test.jpg",final);
```

but the image is created with

```
final = Scalar::all(0);
```

So final image is always filled by zeros. Also

```
image.copyTo(final_seg,final);
```

copies "image" into "final_seg" using "final" **as the mask**, so it does copy no element. Perhaps you mean the opposite:

```
image.copyTo(final,final_seg);
```

this copies "image" into "final" using "final_seg" as the mask.